# Azure durable function replay behavior and time limit for normal http-trigger azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Because http-trigger azure function has a strict time limit for 230s, I created a http-trigger durable azure function. I find that when I trigger durable function multiple times and if the last run is not completed, the current run will continue the last run until it is finished. It is a little confused for me because I only want each run to do the task of the current run, not replay the last un-finished run. So my question is that:

1. Is it by design for durable function to make sure each run is completed (succeed or failed)?
2. Can durable function only focus on the current run just like the normal http-trigger azure function?
3. If 2) is not, is there any way to mitigate the time limit issue for normal http-trigger azure function?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. The function runs until it gets results that is ***Successfully completed*** or ***failed*** message.
2. According to [Microsoft-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity#timeout-and-long-running-functions) it says,

> Azure Functions times out after 230 seconds regardless of the `functionTimeout` setting you've configured in the settings.